# custom post types wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type called show.. How do I tell wordpress to go to show.php for loading the content instead of single.php?

This is crucial since single.php does not carry the code for the extra added fields I have, thats why I want to use show.php

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [WordPress docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) say your template file must be `single-show.php`, not just `show.php`.

> **`single-<post-type>.php`**
>
> > The single post template used when a single post from a custom post type is queried. For example, single-books.php would be used for displaying single posts from the custom post type books. index.php is used if the query template for the custom post type is not present.

Answer (score 0):

1.Copy `single.php`.

2.Rename it `single-show.php`.

3.Now modify this template as per your requirement.